# I am getting the following error: [GraphQL error]: Message: Task

Tags: graphql, apollo-client, graphql-js, prisma, prisma-graphql

I am getting this error (using prisma and graphql), still after looking it up I have no clue what's going on.

Would anyone please help? Thank you!

> [Network error]: Error: Task
> slick.basic.BasicBackend$DatabaseDef$$anon$2@3a22bdca rejected from
> slick.util.AsyncExecutor$$anon$2$$anon$1@cfc0ea7[Running, pool size =
> 1, active threads = 0, queued tasks = 1000, completed tasks = 497]
>
> Error: Task slick.basic.BasicBackend$DatabaseDef$$anon$2@3a22bdca
> rejected from
> slick.util.AsyncExecutor$$anon$2$$anon$1@cfc0ea7[Running, pool size =
> 1, active threads = 0, queued tasks = 1000, completed tasks = 497]

[image]

Any other information I can provide to help debugging?

Answer (score 1):

Are you using Prisma's demo servers, and is it working correctly now?

I experienced the exact same error yesterday, even the same `completed tasks = 497`.  In my troubleshooting, the same error happened when 1) I tried to view the Prisma admin console, and 2) when I tried to pull down the schema from Prisma, so I figured the error was coming from something on Prisma's end and it was out of my control.

Today I tried the same things again and they're working correctly! Hopefully they are for you too.

Comment: Yes - Prisma's demo server.

Comment: Great, glad to hear!